# Change the value of the pointer inside a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I wanted to change the value of a pointer to point to a different address from inside a function.
I know I need a pointer to pointer to do that but I made a typo mistake and used `char *` instead of `char **` and I got the results below.

Passing the *address* of the pointer `ptr1` in the function `func`, the pointer `p` becomes a pointer that points to the address of a pointer.
So if I dereference the pointer `*p` I'll be able to change the value that it points to, in that case the (value of) pointer `ptr1`.
I know I cannot access the data that `ptr1` points to (I'd need a `char ** p` argument for that).

But if my only intention is to change the address that `ptr1` points to, would that be acceptable in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char array1[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7',};
char array2[10] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G',};

void func(char * p)
{
    printf("func is called\n");
    *p = array2;
}

int main(void)
{
    char * ptr1 = NULL;
    ptr1 = array1;

    printf("ptr1 = %s\n", ptr1);
    func(&ptr1);
    printf("ptr1 = %s\n", ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result I get.

```
ptr1 = 1234567
func is called
ptr1 = ABCDEFG
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong and you (un)luckyly got the desired output with your wrong code.

The function `func` is modifying only one byte based on the passed pointer because the pointer is `char*`.

It seems you are using little-endian environment and the address of first elements of `array1` and `array2` happened to be same other than the lowest byte, so the value of `ptr1` after the modification happened to be correct by modifying only one byte.

Try replacing

```
char array1[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7',};
char array2[10] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G',};
```

with

```
char array1[256] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7',};
char array2[256] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G',};
```

(change the number of elements of the arrays) and you *may* get another result. If you failed to get another result, try another size.

Comment: I'm glad that someone said my code is wrong. I got surprised and frustrated at the same time when I saw that. Yes, it fails to change the pointer if I change the size (it points to the same address. But I tried with `int array` and I get the same results as before even if I change the size of the arrays.